# How to call multiple click via single button click

Tags: .net

I have two buttons in my page. I wish that when I click on single button both buttons actions must be fire. Here I am sharing My code

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Insert(sender, e);
   **EmployeeFormView_ItemInserting(sender,  Insert);** 
}
    public void EmployeeFormView_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
    {


        TextBox SexTextBox = (TextBox)form1.FindControl("SexTextBox");
        TextBox dobTextBox = (TextBox)form1.FindControl("dobTextBox");
        TextBox office_addressTextBox = (TextBox)form1.FindControl("office_addressTextBox");


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        com.Connection = conn;
        com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employees Values('" + SexTextBox.Text + "','" + dobTextBox.Text + "', '" + office_addressTextBox.Text + "')";
        conn.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("Record inserted successfully");
        bindgrid();
        conn.Close();
    }
   public void Insert(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Lets validate the page first
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;

        int intResult = 0;
        // Page is valid, lets go ahead and insert records
        // Instantiate BAL object

        PersonBAL pBAL = new PersonBAL();
    // Instantiate the object we have to deal with
    Person person = new Person();

        // set the properties of the object
        person.a_select_part = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        person.a_dalal_name = TextBox2.Text;
        person.a_owner_name = TextBox3.Text;
        person.a_mobile_number = TextBox4.Text;


        try
        {
            intResult = pBAL.research(person);
            if (intResult > 0)
                TextBox1.Text = "pankil";
            else
                TextBox1.Text = "FirstName [<b>" + TextBox1.Text + "</b>] alredy exists, try another name";

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = ee.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            person = null;
            pBAL = null;


        }

    }
```

Now what arguments should I pass to

> EmployeeFormView_ItemInserting(sender,);

Answer (score 0):

To perform the actions of two buttons in the same page by clicking one button, you need to call the button click event of the second button in the first button Ie.,

```
this.Button2.PerformClick();
```

Comment: it is giving me error that " does not contain definition of PerformClick();

Comment: you are using vb.net? or c#?